# c# assembly references i don't use

Tags: c#, build, .net-assembly

How can i get dependency's assembly, that i don't use?

In .sln file i added ProjectDependency B,C in my project A

```
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "A", "A\A.csproj", "{BF8FD60F-8519-4DD5-8576-2E6AB68AC640}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {99BEBDF2-B5AE-4900-9BC2-7F0B4A1CDEA1} = {99BEBDF2-B5AE-4900-9BC2-7F0B4A1CDEA1}
        {C8FC5959-A63A-4C0C-B245-BC21FA2027A6} = {C8FC5959-A63A-4C0C-B245-BC21FA2027A6}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject

Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "B", "Dependencies\B\B.csproj", "{C8FC5959-A63A-4C0C-B245-BC21FA2027A6}"
EndProject

Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "C", "Dependencies\C\C.csproj", "{99BEBDF2-B5AE-4900-9BC2-7F0B4A1CDEA1}"
EndProject
```

But i cant get this dependencies in execution time

I tried write this code in A project

```
var results1 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

var results2 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();
```

to get this B and C dependencies. I didn't find them in results1, results2 variable.

EDIT:
I know about way to load assembly by path:

```
Assembly.Load()
```

But it doesn't look like flex solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make some fake (empty) class/static property in projects B and C and reference somewhere it in project A. In that way compiler will include your assemblies in build time.

Comment: Then it will be dependencies, that i use :(
I search way get assembly without using any classes/static property from them

Comment: From where then do you expect to load this assembly? Only way i can think of is as embedded resources. As far I understand that solution is just kind of container for projects. Things what's get compiled are projects itself.